# C++ remove substring from char

Tags: c++, replace, char, substring

I am pretty new to C++ and that's why I need some help.

In Python I would do it this way:

```
myString = "test|arg"
myArg = myString.split("|")[0]
```

But now I am in C++ and I am having a char and want to kinda remove a special part.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

bool isPartOf(const std::string& word, const std::string& sentence) {
    return sentence.find(word) != std::string::npos;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        char* myChar= "test|me";
        if (isPartOf("|me", myChar)) {
            std::string sStr(myChar);
            boost::replace_all(sStr, "|me", "");
            std::copy(sStr.begin(), sStr.end(), myChar);
            myChar[sStr.size()] = '\0';
            printf(myChar);
            system("pause>nul");
        }

}
```

That's my current code but I get this error:

> Error  1   error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that >may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values >are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See >documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'    c:\program files >(x86)\vc\include\xutility 2132    1   ConsoleApplication2

I hope someone could help me

Best regards

Comment: in c++ you would maybe use `std::string` instead of a `char*`

Comment: Your code overwrites a literal string. You must not do that.

Answer (score 2):

C++ equivalent to your Python program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
  std::string myString = "test|me";
  std::string myArg = myString.substr(0, myString.find('|'));
  std::cout << myArg << std::endl;
}
```

**output**

```
test
```